# UISearchbar Keyboard not dismissing

Tags: ios, uiview, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have a view controller whose view is setup in such a way that it has 3 buttons and other subviews. On clicking one of the buttons(3rd button), i am adding another view controller's view as subview to `self.view`  (in this view i have a search display controller in the active state with keyboard)

I'm able to achieve this using the following code

```
 [self.searchDisplayController setActive:YES];
    [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar setShowsCancelButton:NO];
    [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar becomeFirstResponder];
```

Now when i press the 2nd button, i try removing this view from the superview and also try to resign the keyboard in the `viewWillDisappear` (`[self.view endEditing:YES]`) in the following manner, but keyboard still doesnt resign

One small edit, it is resigning in case i comment out the following piece of code

```
- (BOOL)searchBarShouldEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {

    if (self.dataSource.count)
        return YES;
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: adding subviews or removing subviews will not call your `viewWillAppear` or `viewWillDisappeare` method. Those methods are called only when you push or present controller.

Answer (score 0):

Try to resign UISearchBar in `viewWillDisappear`

```
[yourSearchBar resignFirstResponder];
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the method that is called to your 2nd button, just type in

```
 [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar resignFirstResponder];
```

Leave the viewWillDisappear alone. That is for when the view is done with whatever animation it is doing, and when the view is leaving. If you set the display controller to resigning the responder, it should make it go away immediately.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using NSNotificationCenter as below.

//.m file:

> [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self
>   selector:@selector(ResignFirstResponder:) name:@"resign" object:nil];

in ResignFirstResponder:

> [searchBar resignFirstResponder];

in which class you use above addObserver, you have to implement that method.

//.m file from where you want to send action, call method as below. [on your second button click]

> [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"resign"
>   object:nil];